# How to load an object onload with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, rest

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html x-ng-app="demo">
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
    <script src="../demo/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../demo/js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../demo/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../demo/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../demo/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../demo/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../demo/js/employee_service.js"></script>
    <script src="../demo/js/employee_controller.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <form name="demo_form">
        <div x-ng-controller="EmployeeController">
            <h1> {{Employee.name}} </h1>
            <span> </span>
            <ul>
                <li x-ng-repeat="address in employee.addresses">
                 {{address.address1}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my service script

```
var module = angular.module('demo', []);
module.service('EmployeeService', function($http){

    this.get = function(id){
        var method = "GET";
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/rest/employee/get/" + id;
        console.log(url);

        $http({
            method : method,
            url : url,
            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
        }).then(onSuccess, onError);

        function onSuccess(response){
            console.log('got it');
            return response.data;
        }

        function onError(response){
            console.log(response.statusText);
        }

    }

});
```

This is my controller

```
 //module.controller('EmployeeController', function ($scope, $routeParams EmployeeService) { //This line give an error but it is not related to the question
module.controller('EmployeeController', function ($scope, EmployeeService) {

    //var paramEmployeeID = $routeParams.params1;
    var paramEmployeeID = 1;
    //Here it doesn't wait for the onSuccess method from the service which will deliver the object.
    $scope.employee = EmployeeService.get(paramEmployeeID);
    //$scope.employee = angular.copy(EmployeeService.get(paramEmployeeID));
    console.log($scope.employee);
});
```

The error comes when the page loads and starts with the service and then controller. That's why it tries to load first the employee then it doesn't wait for the onSuccess method and it jumps to the controller to continue and finally comes back to the service to execute the onSuccess method which executes too late because it returns the object but in the controller I already got the undefined object. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How you are getting value in $scope.newEmployee and from where you are calling save() function?

Comment: $scope.newEmployee is bound from another page with ng-model. And in that page there's a button that calls the save method. I pasted my controller as-is with the save function which is irrelevant to the question. In fact the problem it was just the lines below the $scope.save method. I updated my question to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: which browser u are using? Actually i am facing a problem in posting daya from angular to API. It works fine with IE but in chrome it gives 'Preflight error'..can u help

Comment: I'm using Chrome 52 64bits. What I posted before worked fine for me. I added the ng-controller to the html tag and all my input fields are linked to the newEmployee model for each instance variable. I think your problem is the Content-Type in your header. Are you trying to send the object as json? As you saw previously on my question, I defined: headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'} in the $http and then the data property of the $http I set data: angular.toJson(employee).

Comment: i tried your code but still m having same problem - 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:58365/home/saveEmpData. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async issue. You can chain the promise. Try:

On the service make sure you return the promise:

```
this.get = function(id){
    var method = "GET";
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/rest/employee/get/" + id;
    console.log(url);

    function onSuccess(response){
        console.log('got it');
        return response.data;
    }

    return $http({
        method : method,
        url : url,
        headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
    }).then(onSuccess, onError);

}
```

In the controller you can chain it to get the data that you need:

```
EmployeeService.get(paramEmployeeID).then(function(employee){
   $scope.employee = employee;
   console.log($scope.employee);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get this error: angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined